# Error adding an attribute and length restriction on a complex type

Tags: java, spring, web-services, xsd, xsd-validation

We have a request XSD that we use in our system and have a Spring Web service that used this request XSD.

Everything compiles and deployed correctly. I can type the WSDL url into IE and view it. I can navigate to the request XSD in IE. So nothing seems to be wrong with the request XSD.
But  when I am trying to call the web service via SOAP UI: create a new project and add the WSDL and hit OK I get the following error

```
ERROR:error: src-ct.2: To Extend the specified base type ‘Name@*MyNAMESPACE*‘ it must be a simple type or be a complex type with simple content.
```

In my XSD I have a name field

```
<xs:simpleType name="Name">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And then I use this in several places where I extend it by adding an attribute

```
<xs:complexType name="MyCustomeName">
      <xs:simpleContent>
             <xs:extension base="mc:Name">
                    <xs:attribute name="MyTypeOfName" fixed="MCN"/>
             </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

From what I can see the only way to enforce a length restriction and add an attribute is like the way I have defined it.

No idea what is defined incorrectly. Any ideas?

---

As requested here is my WSDL of the service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="the-location"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.mycomp.com/myowndir/"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  targetNamespace="http://schemas.mycomp.com/myowndir/"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema>
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.mycomp.com/myowndir/"
                       schemaLocation="../xsd/MyRequest-1.0.xsd"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.mycomp.com/myowndir/"
                       schemaLocation="../xsd/MyResponse-1.0.xsd"/>

            <xs:element name="TheServiceResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="MessageId" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="TheServiceRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="TheServiceRequestPart" element="TheServiceRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="TheServicePlanResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="TheServiceResponsePart" element="TheServiceResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="TheServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="MyOperation">
            <wsdl:input message="TheServiceRequest" name="TheServiceRequestInput"/>

            <wsdl:output message="TheServicePlanResponse" name="TheServicePortTypeResponseOutput"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="TheServiceBinding" type="TheServicePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="MyOperation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.mycomp.com/myowndir/MyOperation"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="TheService">
        <wsdl:port binding="TheServiceBinding" name="TheServiceIntegrationPort">
            <soap:address location="/the-location/the-service"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Hi, I think that your type definitions are correct, can you share your wsdl in order to do some tries? maybe the error is in another place.

Comment: Thx albciff. I have added the WSDL. Had to change some values with dummy values.

Comment: Hi @Chrispie can you share also MyRequest-1.0.xsd and MyResponse-1.0.xsd. Besides in your wsdl <xs:element name="TheServiceRequest"> is missing.

Comment: The actual web service has been out sourced to a 3rd party team They basically just uses our request/response XSD's. They are using JDK6 + Spring 3.1. Seems like when we take the WSDL from the server SOAP UI fails but if we load the WSDL from the local file system, SOAP UI loads it correctly. Then we just change the end point to point to the server. Then all is fine. So for now this is what we will use. Thanks for your help